# Get file and save the file in a folder - Angular 2 / Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I use input file and I would like to get my file and save it in a folder. And I find multer but I don't arrive.

```
<ion-content>
    <div #myChart></div>
    <div class="modal-body">
       <input type="file" (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)" placeholder="Upload file..." />
    </div>


</ion-content>

  public fileChangeEvent(fileInput: any){
        if (fileInput)
        {
            let files = fileInput.target.files;
            if (files[0]["type"] === "")
            {
                console.log(files[0]["name"]);
                console.log(files);

        }else{
                //notification le type est incorrect
                alert("Pas bon type");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/ did you check this

Comment: Yes but I have a error with @ionic-native